# Как сделать автозавершение строки в DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Использую DataGridTemplateColumn вместо обычного DataGridTextColumn, т.к. мне не нравится отсутствие враппинга текста(Длинный текст).

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="Текст вопроса" MaxWidth="200">
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Text, 
           UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Проблема в том, что при нажатии `ENTER` элемент не создается, а происходит перевод строки. Как добиться поведения как у `PlaceHolder`?

Возможно, у меня не верный подход и враппинга текста можно было добиться иначе. Буду рад подсказке)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может быть мне следует отследить потерю фокуса через iteraction trigger и просто добавить элемент в коллекцию? Откуда тогда брать, то что уже ввели?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не нужен `DataGridTemplateColumn`, используйте обычный `DataGridTextColumn`:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Текст вопроса" MaxWidth="200">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Если вам нужен перенос текста также в режиме редактирования ячейки, добавьте еще сюда:

```
    <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
            <!--Это часть стандартного стиля, см.
            https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/Controls/DataGridTextColumn.cs,57-->
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
```

Comment: Как в вашей голове все это помещается! Спасибо, Андрей! Выручили уже бессчетное кол-во раз)

Comment: А и не помещается, главное понять принцип, решение становится очевидным :)